# How to avoid plus sign to create a line feed in a rdlc textbox

Tags: rdlc

I need to print an encrypted string as is in a rdlc report. My problem is if the string contain a plus sign it creates a new line in the Textbox. How to avoid this?

Comment: More information and an example of an" encrypted string".

Comment: Nerl6I/+9TzbJRpkbvSA8RhmIeIGLo0bO3cd5E/Upp/lP9qkWkQ1S1Sn5fJAcAHSoRDoCUefy  when is displayed in the PDF add a page break before the plus sign. I already use Replace " " to "". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption produces output that is binary and contains many bytes that have no displayable representation.

Because of this if encrypted data needs to be displayed it is generally either Base64 (best for computers) or hexadecimal (best for people) encoded.

It seems that you may have base64 encoded encrypted data and that is generally composed of the upper and lowercase characters, the 10 digits, "+", "/" and "=". You can not delete these and expect to recover the encrypted data.

If these characters present a problem they can be many times be escaped in some manor or another encoding can be chosen such as hexadecimal or an alternate Base64 character set, see [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If you choose an alternate Base64 character set interoperability will most likely be impaired.

- Note: More information would produce a better answer.

Comment: In Mexico, all invoicing is controlled by our Internal Revenue System. The process is: we sent an XML with data of the invoice and the Revenue System return an XML with what they call "digital signature and certification" of the invoice. This XML data must be shown in the invoice along with the normal info (client name, ítems purchased, etc). I am using rdlc reports for reporting. .

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace the "+" with "÷".

Users don't notice is it since the PDF is just a visual representation of the CFDI, I haven't had any issues with it.